# Why do the GameObject squares have a scale of almost 6 when the scale is set to 1?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a grid of `GameObject` squares to use as game tiles. But when I run Play Mode all the squares are overlapping. And I changed the X and Y positions of the first tile in the inspector to show the scale problem.
[image: just made up a sample png sprite in preview to test the grid]

Create.cs and Node.cs are my only scripts. And Create.cs is a component on `WorldContinent` which is at `position` 0,0,0 and has `scale` 1,1,1. And has no renderer. I added the redundant setting to localScale just to see if that would help. The Node class doesn't affect scale at all.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;

public class Create : MonoBehaviour
{
    //tile found in assets/prefabs/world/tile
    public GameObject gameTile;

    int rows;
    int columns;
    List<Node[]> rowsList = new List<Node[]>();
    Node node;
    int _row;
    int _column;
    float spacing = 1.0f;


    void Start()
    {
        rows = 3;
        columns = 3;

        TurnRowsAndColumnsIntoTilesAndNodes();
    }

    private void TurnRowsAndColumnsIntoTilesAndNodes()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            rowsList.Add(new Node[columns]);

            for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
            {
                _row = row;
                _column = column;
                GameObject newTile = NodeAndTileInstatiator();
                rowsList[_row][_column] = node;
                MakeConnectionsToNeighborNodes();
                newTile.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private GameObject NodeAndTileInstatiator()
    {
        float row = _row * spacing;
        float column = _column * spacing;

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(row, column, 0);


        GameObject newTIle = Instantiate(gameTile, position, Quaternion.identity);

        node = new Node(newTIle);
        return newTIle;
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you are mistaking scale with size. Scale is a multiplier of the size. The size of your squares depends on the sprite size and its pixels per unit setting and then tha is multiplied by scale.

Comment: @Nikaas If you want to put this up as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale in the `Transform` component is a multiplier of the GameObject's size.

For a sprite displayed by a `SpriteRenderer` the size in the scene is determined by the `sprite size` divided by its `Pixels Per Unit` setting. For example a sprite with a size of 32x32 pixels and its Pixels Per Unit set at 16 the scene size will be 2x2 units. Then that "base" size  is multiplied by the `Transform`'s scale (say 1.5x1.5) to arrive at 3x3 units in the scene.